# How to use cloudflare workers to bypass ad Blockers restrictions?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, fingerprintjs2, fingerprintjs

I am trying to load fingerprintjs script in a google chrome browser where Ublock origin is enabled but it's impossible with my current situation :

```
<script>  // Initialize the agent at application startup.  const fpPromise = import('https://fpcdn.io/v3/your-public-api-key')
    .then(FingerprintJS => FingerprintJS.load({
      endpoint: 'https://fp.yourdomain.com'    }));

  // When you need the visitor identifier:  fpPromise    .then(fp => fp.get())
    .then(result => console.log(result.visitorId));
</script>
```

At the page load, my browser's console shows :

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://fpcdn.io/v3/your-public-api-key`

Some people suggest to use cloudflare workers to evade Ublock restrictions. But I never used cloudflare I just started my first worker now :

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
 
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  
  return new Response("Hello world")
}
```

How can I use this workers to get my `visitorId` ?

Answer (score 0):

This feature will be released in a couple of weeks and will be part of the product. Nevertheless, there's a public beta that requires some manual steps. If you are interested, reach out to the official support: support@fingerprint.com